# How to use the same minmaxscaler used on the training data with new data?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, time-series, data, feature-scaling

Im using the keras LSTM model to make prediction, and the code above is to scale the data:
inputs are shaped like  (n, 11, 1) and the label is 1D 
**DailyDemand.py**

```
#scaling data
scaler_x = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range =(-1, 1))
x = np.array(x).reshape ((len(x),11 ))
x = scaler_x.fit_transform(x)
scaler_y = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range =(-1, 1))
y = np.array(y).reshape ((len(y), 1))
y = scaler_y.fit_transform(y)

# Split train and test data
x_train=x[0: train_end ,]
x_test=x[train_end +1: ,]
y_train=y[0: train_end]
y_test=y[train_end +1:] 
x_train=x_train.reshape(x_train.shape +(1,))
x_test=x_test.reshape(x_test.shape + (1,))
# Train and save the Model named fit1 in a json and h5 files 
[....]
# serialize model to JSON
model_json = fit1.to_json()
with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
# serialize weights to HDF5
fit1.save_weights("model.h5")
print(">>>> Model saved to model.h5 in the disk")
```

and Now im trying to predict a new values of a new data with this trained model. so i loaded the model from the files:

**predict.py**

```
from DailyDemand import scaler_y
from DailyDemand import scaler_x
[...]
# load json and create model
json_file = open('model.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
# load weights into new model
loaded_model.load_weights("model.h5")
print("Loaded model from disk")

########################################
# make prediction with the loaded model

FeaturesTest = [267,61200,695,677,70600,116700,130200,768,659,741,419300]
xaa = np.array(FeaturesTest).reshape ((1,11 )).astype(float)
print(xaa)
xaa = scaler_x.fit_transform(xaa) 
xaa = xaa.reshape(xaa.shape +(1,))
print("print FeaturesTest scalled: ")
print(xaa) # incorrect scalled value, always returns -1 ones
```

> ```
> xaa = [[[-1.]
>   [-1.]
>   [-1.]
>   [-1.]
>   [-1.]
>   [-1.]
>   [-1.]
>   [-1.]
>   [-1.]
>   [-1.]
>   [-1.]]]
> ```

```
tomorrowDemand = loaded_model.predict(xaa)
print("tomorrowDemand scalled: ", tomorrowDemand)
prediction = scaler_y.inverse_transform(np.array(tomorrowDemand).reshape ((len(tomorrowDemand), 1))).astype(int)
print ("the real demand is 95900 and the prediction is: ", prediction)
```

The problem is how i can use the same scaler used in the training on the new data?
i want to know if i made a mistake in this code to use the same scaller on the new data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are refitting `scaler_x` on your test set, which you don't want.  Change this line:

```
xaa = scaler_x.fit_transform(xaa)
```

to

```
xaa = scaler_x.transform(xaa)
```

You are getting `[-1, -1, ..., -1]` because with one sample, each feature is equal to the minimum.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it works very well, you have saved my day =D.

Comment: Awesome! I'm so glad to help. Can you click the check mark to accept the answer?

Comment: Done, sorry i was busy with the problem and i forgot to check the answer mark :)